# Прокрутка страницы к элементу

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток! Необходимо при загрузке страницы прокручивать к определенному элементу. Делаю так:

```
document.getElementById('elId').scrollIntoView(false)
```

Chrome прокручивает к элементу, затем прокручивает обратно к началу страницы. 
Видел, что на сайте vk.com на странице диалога такая штука есть - страница прокручивается к концу диалога.

Comment: @woland, это же не весь ваш код. Есть еще что-то, что возвращает страницу в исходное положение. А так, [всё нормально работает][1]

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/8Lswf7cc/

Answer (score 2):

```
 var elem = document.getElementById('elId');
    elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
```

это к концу страницы, но можно scrollTop задавать так как тебе нужно.
 Удачи.